# Tkinter weird listbox behavior

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

```py
def possibleClicked(stuff):
    selectedItem = listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
    print(selectedItem)
    listbox.delete(listbox.curselection())
    listbox2.insert(tkinter.END, selectedItem)
    listbox.selection_clear(0, tkinter.END)

root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry("650x400")
root.title("Bazaar Bot - Login")
root.resizable(False, False)



listbox = tkinter.Listbox(root, selectmode=tkinter.SINGLE, exportselection=False, width=15, height=10)
listbox.place(x=400,y=30)
listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", possibleClicked)

for i in settings.possible:
    listbox.insert(tkinter.END, i)
```

In the gif below, I'm spam clicking and the listbox elements do not always call the `possibleClicked()` function, moving my cursor seems to fix this for some reason.

[image: gif of the problem]

Not really sure what the error is, maybe something to do with the currently selected listbox element?

Comment: Does this help if you comment out `#listbox.selection_clear(0, tkinter.END)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that "double click" is a different event that "single click", so you are not actually triggering the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event.
Also note that `listbox.curselection()` will return empty when double clicking.
You need to redefine your code to account for the double click event:

```
def possibleClicked(event):
    global curselect    
    if listbox.curselection():
        curselect = listbox.curselection()

    selectedItem = listbox.get(curselect)    
    listbox.delete(curselect)
    listbox.insert(tkinter.END, selectedItem)
    listbox.selection_clear(0, tkinter.END)

global curselect
curselect = ()
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("650x400")
root.title("Bazaar Bot - Login")
root.resizable(False, False)
listbox = tkinter.Listbox(root, selectmode=tkinter.SINGLE, exportselection=False, width=15, height=10)
listbox.place(x=400, y=30)
listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", possibleClicked)
listbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", possibleClicked)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this with an if statement in both functions, checking if the item in the listbox has no name.

```py
if selectedItem != '':
```

Used here:

```py
def possibleClicked(stuff):
    global curselect
    if possibleListbox.curselection():
        curselect = possibleListbox.curselection()
    selectedItem = possibleListbox.get(curselect)
    possibleListbox.delete(curselect)
    if selectedItem != '': #here
        selectedListbox.insert(tkinter.END, selectedItem)
def selectedClicked(stuff):
    global curselect
    if selectedListbox.curselection():
        curselect = selectedListbox.curselection()
    selectedItem = selectedListbox.get(curselect)
    selectedListbox.delete(curselect)
    if selectedItem != '': #here
        possibleListbox.insert(tkinter.END, selectedItem)
```